# Can't source ROS galactic

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following the installation steps of ros2 galactic on ubuntu 20.04 according to the ros documentation.
Found here: https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html.
I followed everything all the way up to

```
# Replace ".bash" with your shell if you're not using bash
# Possible values are: setup.bash, setup.sh, setup.zsh
 source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash
```

Then i get the error

```
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

I currently have absolutely no idea why this is happening, did some searches online and it seems that no one has had this problem before me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408039/can%27t-source-ros-galactic/) by [sajid1122](https://answers.ros.org/users/103351/sajid1122/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2022-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that my alias formatting for an alias i made previously in the bashrc file was wrong.

Solution:
Remove your alias. Close your terminal and open a new terminal. However, if you want to remove the alias on your current terminal you can run as follows

```
unalias alias-name
```

Read more here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/325368/how-do-i-remove-an-alias

---

Originally posted by [sajid1122](https://answers.ros.org/users/103351/sajid1122/) with karma: 19 on 2022-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0